# Tracking the state of the C# object using visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I am working on a big project, with many dependencies, and somewhere in the code, something is changing the properties of the object I am tracking.

Is there any way of putting a breakpoint on variable, so that the program will stop when the object changes it's state?

Comment: If it is a property then you can put a breakpoint in the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing it to a property for public use, that way you can set a breakpoint on the get/set operations.

```
private int theVariable;
public int TheVariable 
{
  get 
  {
    return theVariable;
  }
  set 
  {
    theVariable = value;
  }
}
```

---

Its also possible to set a breakpoint on when a variable changes value, yes, but I would recommend a property.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa295838(v=vs.60).aspx#_core_setting_a_breakpoint_when_a_variable_changes_value):

> Setting a Breakpoint When a Variable Changes Value To set a breakpoint
>   when a variable changes value From the Edit menu, click Breakpoints.
>
> Click the Data tab of the Breakpoints dialog box.
>
> In the Expression text box, type the name of the variable.
>
> Click OK to set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Conditional Breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce(v=vs.90).aspx)

MSDN says:

> A breakpoint condition is an expression that the debugger evaluates
> when a breakpoint is reached. If the condition is satisfied, the
> debugger looks at the How to: Specify a Hit Count to determine whether
> to break (or execute another specified action).

This allows you to put expressions when you can tell Visual Studio to break.